# Sorting 2d array which store 10 city names

Tags: arrays, c, string, sorting, multidimensional-array

Hi I am beginner in c and Want to sort 10 city names which is stored in 2d array 
For example,
"goa" print first and "mumbai" print after "goa" 
becuase in goa g come first compared to m in mumbai

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){

    char str[10][20]={"mumbai","goa","kanpur","bhopal","delhi","nagpur","jabalpur","thane","bhandup","kurla"};

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<10;j++)
        {
            int p = strcmp(str[i],str[j]);
            if(p==-1 || p==0)
                continue;
            else
            {
                char tmp[1][20];
                tmp[0] = str[i];
                str[i] = str[j];
                str[j]= tmp[0];
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n",str[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

above code not working but when I use below part of code in second **for loop** then its working

```
strcpy(tmp, str[i]);
strcpy(str[i], str[j]);
strcpy(str[j], tmp);
```

can anyone explain me why this below logic is wrong in detail

```
tmp[0] = str[i];
str[i] = str[j];
str[j]= tmp[0];
```

Comment: This does not even compile. What compiler are you using?

Comment: gcc mingw-18.0 version it is compiling

Comment: Checking the return value from `strcmp` against an explicit number other than 0 may end in sadness. The only guarantee is a positive or negative value when the strings don't match, not `-1`. Use `< 0` or `> 0`.

Comment: The short explanation is that in C the `=`  operator can't be used to assign the value of a string to another string. To do that you need `strcpy`

Comment: That said... why make your own sorting. Just use `qsort`

Comment: @SupportUkraine did you have detailed explanation why we are not able to use `=` operation while assign the value of a string to another string OR you can give me any website link because I am not able to find perfect explanation.
Thank you !!!!

Comment: In C strings are really char arrays. In most situations arrays are converted to pointers. So when you use `=` you actually try to assign one pointer value to another instead of assigning one string to another...

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, tmp[0] = str[i] would be assigning the address of the storage location for str[i] as the new address for the storage location of tmp[0]. Imaging putting your name on someone else's house.

strcpy is taking all the data in one row and copying it to the other row. Imagine asking a builder for a house just like your neighbor has.

Answer (score 0):

> why this below logic is wrong in detail

Array are not pointers.  Pointers are not arrays.

A *string* is a sequence of characters, up to and including the *null character* - usually stored in an *array*.

`tmp[0] = str[i];` attempts to copy a pointer `str[i]` to an *array*.

Any form of `a = b`, does not copy a string or array, but perhaps a *pointer*.  Copying pointers is insufficient for OP's swapping of *strings*.

To copy a *string*, use `strcpy(c, d)` to copy the *string* pointed to by `d` to the destination, pointed to by `d`.